# SharePoint 2010 error when applying a target audience

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, error, audience-targeting

I am experiencing a problem when trying to apply a target audience to a navigation link. It looks like it is being applied and when I go back to double check it I can see the target. When I refresh the page it's no longer there. I have this from multiple machines and using IE 8 through 11 all experiencing the same results. The thing that baffles me the most is an out of state Site Guru said he used my credentials and that he experienced no problems at all.

I have no access to the ULS Logs so I have no insight that is helpful at this point.

I have read billyjimjack's question but using different browsers has not helped. I have also tried Foxfire and Chrome with the same results.

Comment: check this http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx#BM3

Answer (score 0):

couple of things to make sure:

- First off, have a “User Profile Service Application” running!!!! –
  that was my mistake, i did not have one.
- On the site collection you need to activate the “..Publishing
  Feature” for both, the “Website features” and the “Site Collection
  Features”.
- If you intend to use it on a “sub website” – same here, activate the
  “..publishing feature..” within the website features
- If the link refers to a list – go to the list settings and activate
  the “target audience” check box under “..Target Audience”!

http://blog.redefine.at/2012/05/10/sharepoint-2010-navigation-links-and-target-audience/

Answer (score 0):

What it ended up being was the restrictions in our corporate firewall. I had to add the sites into my trusted zones and then change the compatibility settings to match